# MainActivity's OnCreate got called everytime I resume my app. (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using XF pcl. (Appcompat for android)

MainActivity's OnCreate got called everytime I resume my app. 
That means my app re-launched everytime I resume app right?

Is it normal behavior? or I should check my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you call finish() somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I found interesting thing!. If I resume from multitasking screen, it's fine. But I resume by pressing app icon. It makes app restart. Is it correct? Is that different from iOS. @DominiqueLorre

Comment: Yes it calls onCreate but not everything restarts.

Comment: [Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)] solved my problem! @DominiqueLorre

Comment: good catch the doc is not very clear

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even look doc ;;

Answer (score 6):

[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]

solve my problem.

Comment: Note that `LaunchMode.SingleTop` will still create a new instance if it is not on the **top** of the task. Instead using `LaunchMode.SingleTask` ensures that any current activity is reused (singleton). Ref: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959